# Verifying Stokes’ Thm. $\vec F = \left< -y,x,-2\right>$ where $S$ is the region defined by $z^2 = x^2 + y^2, \space z \in [0,4]$

Tags: surface-integrals, line-integrals, stokes-theorem

I want to verify Stokes’ Theorem by evaluating both the left and right side of the following eqn.

$$\int_C \vec F \cdot d\vec r = \int \int_S curl \vec F \cdot d\vec S$$

where $\vec F = \left< -y,x,-2\right>$ and $S$ is the region defined by $z^2 = x^2 + y^2, \space z \in [0,4]$.

When I use the parameterization $\vec r = \left< \cos \theta, \sin \theta, z\right>$

I get a normal vector $\vec n = \left< \cos\theta, \sin \theta,0\right>$ and since $curl \vec F = \left<0,0,2 \right>$

$$curlf \vec F \cdot \vec n = 0$$

so the right hand side equals zero.

Here is what I am not sure since it has been a while since I have evaluated line integrals.

I believe that $C$ is the projection of $S$ onto the $xy$-plane, so it will be a circle with radius $16$.

So, the parameterization I choose is $\vec r = \left< 4\cos \theta, 4\sin \theta, 0\right>$

and because $\vec F = \left<-4\sin\theta, 4\cos\theta,-2 \right>$

$$\vec F \cdot \vec r = 0$$

hence the left side is equal to zero.

Can anyone confirm that I did this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, both RHS and LHS have mistakes that have led to you getting integrals as zero.

**A)** For RHS, your parametrization is not correct. The correct parametrization is

$\vec r(\rho,\theta) = (\rho \cos\theta, \rho \sin\theta, \rho)$, as $z = \rho$ from the equation of the cone.

$r'_{\rho} \times r'_{\theta} = (\rho \cos\theta, \rho \sin \theta, - \rho)$

$0 \leq \rho \leq 4, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Can you now complete the integral?

**B)** For LHS which is line integral, you should have the $z$ component in your parametrization though it would not matter here.

$\vec r(\theta) = (4\cos\theta, 4\sin\theta, 4)$

Now we are supposed to do $\vec F \cdot \vec {r} \ '$ and **not** $\vec F \cdot \vec r$. That was the mistake in your working of LHS.

$r'_{\theta} = (- 4 \sin\theta, 4 \cos\theta, 0)$

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Can you complete the working now?

**Last point** - the outward normal vector for the given cone surface is pointing downward and that is why we have taken $z$ component negative in the first working. Now align the orientation of the boundary curve to the orientation of the surface in your line integral.

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you.  I actually have been a math instructor myself and your explanation is spot on, and I can tell that you understand and know how to teach this very well.

One more question that I have if you don't mind answering, when I calculate $\vec r_{\rho} \times \vec r_{\theta}$ I get the opposite of what you have.  I am thinking that it is related to your last point comment, but I did not catch what you meant.  Can you elaborate that a little?

Comment: Yes that is correct. In that cross product, if we keep $r'_{\theta}$ first, we will get an opposite sign. It does not matter much. We change the sign after cross product, if necessary, in line with the orientation of the surface that we want. Now can you visualize the surface of the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$? Its radius is zero at $z = 0$ and keeps increasing in proportion to the height ($z$) of the cone. Now which direction will the _outward_ normal vector from this surface point in?

Comment: and thank you for your kind words.